# Is it possible to reference a variable with an interpolated string?

Tags: sass

I have a list of categories, from which I would like to set a background-color. I would like to keep the values for the background colors as variables. Is it possible to reference a variable by string interpolation? Sass is throwing an "Invalid CSS" error on me currently using this code:

```
/* Category Colors */
$family_wellness_color: #c1d72e;
$lifestyle_color: #f4eb97;
$food_color: #f78f1e;
...

/* Categories */
@each $cat in family_wellness, lifestyle, food
{
    .#{$cat}
    {
        .swatch, .bar
        {
            background-color: $#{$cat}_color;
        }
    }
}
```

Possible? I would really appreciate some advice!

Comment: While I have not tried this before, I am pretty sure this is not supported. I can't find it under [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) or other applicable sections. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not coming with a very elegant solution either. I would really prefer not to have to create a class for each categorical color, but I'm leaning toward doing that so I could use @extend .#{$cat}_background_color (or whatever) inside the loop.

Comment: It may be possible to use @function or write an extension, perhaps (I am fairly certain the variables should be accessible in these contexts).

Comment: [Sass::Environment](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Environment.html) is the context needed; does it happen to be `self` inside a @function? If so, then `var(var($x).value + "_color")` or similar might work

Comment: Hi @pst. I'm using Sass and Compass standalone on a Django project. My Ruby skills are extremely rusty. After some Googling, I did find a couple of examples on how to write custom functions. Given my time constraints, I'm going to have to come back to this later, but I'll post my findings. Thanks, Brandon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the closest I could get to what I wanted was:

```
#_variables.scss
/* Categories */
$family_wellness_color: #c1d72e;
$lifestyle_color: #f4eb97;
$food_color: #f78f1e;
$media_entertainment_color: #db3535;
$travel_recreation_color: #e30e61;
$education_color: #92278f;
$sports_color: #0070bb;
$technology_color: #00b5cc;
$products_shopping_color: #028e99;
$companies_businesses_color: #56BA42;

#_mixins.scss
@import 'variables';

@mixin get_category_bkgd_color($category_name)
{
    @if $category_name == family_wellness
    {
        @include bkgd_color($family_wellness_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == lifestyle
    {
        @include bkgd_color($lifestyle_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == food
    {
        @include bkgd_color($food_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == media_entertainment
    {
        @include bkgd_color($media_entertainment_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == travel_recreation
    {
        @include bkgd_color($travel_recreation_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == education
    {
        @include bkgd_color($education_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == sports
    {
        @include bkgd_color($sports_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == technology
    {
        @include bkgd_color($technology_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == products_shopping
    {
        @include bkgd_color($products_shopping_color);
    }
    @else if $category_name == companies_businesses
    {
        @include bkgd_color($companies_businesses_color);
    }
}

#dashboard.scss
@import 'variables', 'mixins';

@each $cat in family_wellness, lifestyle, food, media_entertainment, travel_recreation, education, sports, technology, products_shopping, companies_businesses
{
    .#{$cat}
    {
        .swatch, .bar
        {
            @include get_category_bkgd_color($cat);
        }
    }
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it does get me a mixin I can re-use in several other areas. Does anyone see a way to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

With Rails 3.1, you can create templates like this: `screen.css.scss.erb` - it comes with all the goodness of scss and erb.

```
<% [...].each do |category_name| %>
  @include bkgd_color($<%= category_name %>_color);
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using sass standalone on Django and .NET MVC projects, but I'll have to try this out.

Answer (score 2):

.html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="family"></li>
    <li class="life"></li>
    <li class="food"></li>
</ul>
```

.scss:

```
$family_color: #c1d72e;
$life_color: #f4eb97;
$food_color: #f78f1e;

// solution 1 - using direct (key, value) pair
@each $cat, $cat_var in (family, $family_color), (life, $life_color), (food, $food_color) {
    .#{$cat} {
        background-color: $cat_var;
    }
}

// solution 2 - using nth function 
@each $cat in (
    family $family_color,
    life $life_color,
    food $food_color) {
      .#{nth($cat, 1)} {
          background-color: nth($cat, 2);
      }
}

// solution 3 - using sass map
$colors: (
    family_color: #c1d72e,
    life_color: #f4eb97,
    food_color: #f78f1e
);

@function color($key){
    @if map-has-key($colors, $key){
        @return map-get($colors, $key);
    }
}

@each $color in family, life, food{
    .#{$color}{
        background-color: color(#{$color}_color);
    }
}
```