# How do I reference a variable by its name in SASS?

Tags: sass

I am working on a sass framework that has a list of variables to turn on and off features.

For example:

```
// atoms:

   $use-pa: true;
   $use-pt: true;
   $use-pb: true;
```

I want to be able to do something like the following in case a variable was turned off.

```
@mixin requires($collection: ()) {

    @each $var in $collection {

        #{$var}: true;

    }
}
```

and

```
@include requires((

    $use-pa,

    $use-pt,

    $use-pb

));
```

I am looking for a way to change a variable's value by its name... if possible. #{} does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reference a variable with an interpolated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010013/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-variable-with-an-interpolated-string)

Comment: You can use maps http://viget.com/extend/sass-maps-are-awesome

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the variable's value, don't use interpolation.
Here's a [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3d5919cac8d16e8960216d10f9018573) for you to play with.