# How to print the class, if there is a variable name

Tags: css, less

I have a variable:

```
@test: this_is_var;
```

And I have class

```
.my-@{test}-class{}
```

**How to print this class in another class?**

This code is wrong:

```
.test-class{
    .my-@{test}-class();
}
```

But this code is work fine

```
.test-class{
    .my-this_is_var-class();
}
```

Why? And how to print this class: `.my-@{test}-class()`?

Comment: There's no way (you can't invoke a mixin by a "dynamic name", though eventually this is planned to be supported indirectly via mixin references). See disscussion at [#1399](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1399#issuecomment-33021350) for why direct "variable interpolation in mixin call" feature would be a bad practice. If you provide your use-case I'm pretty sure we could recommend a better solution.

Comment: Up for a use-case reference!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reference a variable with an interpolated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010013/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-variable-with-an-interpolated-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong variant works nice in codepen.
Maybe you must write `~{}` in your variable. [Here is](http://codepen.io/ostinred/pen/KpLRLR) an example.